# Apache Commons BeanUtils get list properties

Tags: java, generics, apache-commons-beanutils

In Apache Commons BeanUtil, how to get a type inside a list ? for example

```
class Track {
   List<Actor> actorList = new ArrayList<Actor>();
}

System.err.println(PropertyUtils.getPropertyType(trackBean, "actorList"));
// it should give me Actor instead of java.util.List
```

Thanks.

Comment: All generic types are subject to type erasure, so at runtime there is no way Java knows that this is a list of actors. I do not know bean utils, but for this to work this must be solved at compile time.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127923/specifying-generic-collection-type-param-at-runtime-java-reflection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible with beanutils. But you can do so with reflection.

```
Field field = Track.class.getDeclaredField("actorList");
ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType();
Class clazz = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

You will perhaps need a few check above (whether you can cast, whether the actual type arguments exist, etc), but you get the idea.

Type information is erased at runtime, unless it is structural - e.g. the type argument of a field, or of class.